# Carry out multiple get operations using one Stream in Java 8 and save results

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am currently working on program where I would stream through a list, get the first value for one of the fields and save the result.

Product object has two fields (color and name).

I would save the first found name of the Product using Stream like this:

```
List<Product> productList = Arrays.asList(new Product("red", "potatoes"),
  new Product("blue", "orange"), new Product("yellow", "lemon"),
  new Product("brown", "bread"), new Product("pink", "sugar"));

String firstProductName = 
  productList.stream().map(Product::getName).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().get();
```

To save the first found value of color, I would use another Stream:

```
String firstProductColor = 
  productList.stream().map(Product::getColor).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().get();
```

Is there a way to combine those two Streams so that I can extract the first color and first name in one Stream and save to firstProductName and firstProductColor?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Are there any guarantees about null conditions? (null name means null color, etc.) If not, then there's probably not a faster way to do this with streams.

Comment: @lucasvw There is no guarantee about null conditions, so I guess maybe a traditional loop is better in this case. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. If you could accept my answer indicating that your question has been answered, that would be helpful.

Comment: There is an extra `)` at the end of your statements. Besides that, the two statements look fine. What do you expect to gain from combining them into one statement? I mean, can you just *imagine* how such a combined statement should look like, being simpler than declaring two variables and initializing them with an expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for use of streams, but without guarantee of certain null conditions, I don't think that is possible, since the result may come from two distinct elements in the stream.

A solution with a simple for loop is possible:

```
String firstProdName = null;
String firstProdColor = null;
for (Product prod : productList) {
    if (firstProdName == null) // set the product name if not set
         firstProdName = prod.getName();
    if (firstProdColor == null) // set the product color if not set
         firstProdColor = prod.getColor();
    if (firstProdName != null && firstProdColor != null)
         break; // both have been found - terminate loop
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand properly you want to retrieve the first *non-null* product name and product colour and that the first *non-null* product name could well be in a different location within the list than the first non-null colour.

The issue here is the way the stream pipeline is executed i.e we're not passing every element of the stream through the first intermediate operation and then passing all of the elements returned from that intermediate operation through the next intermediate operation and so forth until the terminal operation. Rather each element of the stream is passed *vertically* down the stream pipeline and the first element that passes all the intermediate operations successfully is retrieved with the call to `findFirst().get()`.

Thus, it seems to me that it's *very* *unlikely* to accomplish the task at hand with streams and even if it's possible it will be overcomplicated due to the way the stream pipelines are executed.

Also, note that calling `get()` straight from an [Optional](http://www.baeldung.com/java-optional) is a misuse and you should never use this method unless you're *100%* sure there will be a value present; reasons to be explained later on.

However, using a *for loop* or a *foreach* loop we can get the data required in a single pass through the list for example as suggested by lucaswv's answer.

In addition to the aforementioned, I'd like to point out the misuse of [Optional](http://www.baeldung.com/java-optional). when you do:

```
...findFirst().get()
```

is no different to calling a method that could return null but instead of guarding against null when the method returns a result you'll simply call another method on top of the return value of this method which could lead to a `NullPointerException`.

Conversely, the call to `get()` from an [Optional](http://www.baeldung.com/java-optional) would lead to a `NoSuchElementException` when there is no value present; therefore it's not ideal to use `get()` straight from an [Optional](http://www.baeldung.com/java-optional) result in most cases.

To prevent such exception you'll want to use [OrElse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) to return the value if present else a provide a default value.

Obviously, `Optional.get()` is there for a reason but it's a mistake by the API designers and hence I'd recommend you always use [orElse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) or [orElseGet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, using the following code:

```
Product product = productList.get(0);
String firstProductName = product.getName();
String firstProductColor = product.getColor();
System.out.println(firstProductName + " / " + firstProductColor);
```

Your output will be: `red / potatoes`

There is no need to create a stream in order to get the first element from a `List`. This is the easiest approach.

But if you still want to use a stream, don't devide the list in two streams, use a single one, like this:

```
Product product = productList.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().get();
String firstProductName = product.getName();
String firstProductColor = product.getColor();
System.out.println(firstProductName + " / " + firstProductColor);
```

The output will be the same as above: `red / potatoes`

Comment: You missed the placement not null condition. The first non null colour may be different from the first non null product name. I assume...

Comment: Yes. @BoristheSpider is right here. My concern is that if the first Product contains a null value for either the name or the color, then we would be looking for a non-null value from another Product, in which case looking only into the first Product will not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Streams are not designed for that kind of operations, you should use classic loop instead of stream to obtain multiple values during single traverse of collection.